# Apache Calcite - Access RESTFul Service with SQL

Tags: sql, rest, adapter, apache-calcite

I have went through documentation and its a bit hard for me to grasp how one should go about writing adapter for anything. I want to ease the access of RESTful web services with SQL like interface for business folks.

Coarse requirements look something like:

1. Register data source, in this case endpoint
2. Add mapping for endpoint to table
3. Execute simple select queries
4. Allow joins to be performed on the basis of some join key but in client application memory
5. Represent the output in the tabular format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using Calcite's [file adapter](https://calcite.apache.org/docs/file_adapter.html), which was just added in release 1.12.

The simplest use case is reading and parsing a CSV file from the file system, and presenting it as a table that can be used in a SQL statement. But in addition to files, the file adapter read documents via HTTP, and it can parse the contents of HTML tables. So you should be able to use it to read data from a REST service.

Comment: Sounds like a solution to me. Let me try it and I will post back.